# PHP Repeat n times inside a function

Tags: php, repeat

I am trying to use item[1],item[2]... item[n] inside php functions like array_diff, max etc.

I use foreach loop like this to get the items

```
$n=1;
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $item[$n] = $array;
    $n++;  
}

# how can I define item[1] through item[n] like:
print_r(max(item[1],item[2]...item[n]));
print_r(array_diff(item[1],item[2]...item[n]));
```

I searched but could not find a solution, please point me to the url if this has already been answered. Thanks.

Comment: `$result = call_user_func_array('array_diff', $item);`

Comment: btw: `max()` can also take an array as argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I don't see a problem, you can do this:
Hope it helps

```
foreach ($arrays as $k=>$array) {
    $item[$k] = $array;
}
print_r(max($item));
print_r(array_diff($arrays,$item));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. max is working with this method but array_diff is expecting more items. This is the error I get for array_diff
    Warning: array_diff(): at least 2 parameters are required, 1 given in /home/path/script.php in line 50

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. Now is fixed.

Comment: If this answer your question, you should accept it as best answer.